# if __ and __ in ___ then

Tags: python, list, if-statement, dictionary

I am trying to create a script that loops through a list.

I need to look through a finite list (400) of competency identifiers (e.g. 124, 129 etc - normal ints )

I then have a dictionary that records what competencies each user has. The Key is the user name and the value for each key is a list of integers (i.e. which competencies the users have)

For example

```
User x - [124, 198, 2244 ...]
User Y - [129, 254, 198, 2244 ...]
```

I am looking to compile a matrix highlighting how often each competency occurs with every other competency - an adjacency matrix.

For example in the above examples competency 198 has occurred with competency 2244 on two occasions. Whereas competency 254 and 124 have never occurred together.

I am currently using this code:

```
fe = []    
count = 0
competency_matches = 0
for comp in competencies_list:
    common_competencies = str("")
for comp2 in competencies_list:
    matches = int(0)
    for person in listx:
        if comp and comp2 in d1[person]:
            matches = matches + 1
        else:
            matches = matches
    common_competencies = str(common_competencies) + str(matches) + ","
fe.append(common_competencies)
print fe
print count
count = count + 1
```

This doesnt work and simply returns how many times each competency has occurred overall. I think the problem is with the "if comp and comp2 in d1[person]:" line.

The problem would be, for example, if a person had the following competencies [123, 1299, 1236] and I searched for competency 123, this would be returned twice due to this appearing in the 123 and 1236 entries. Does a way exist to force an EXACT match when using the if __ and __ then operation.

Or does anyone have an improve suggestion how to achieve this ...

Thanks in advance for any pointers. Cheers

Comment: common_competencies = str("")??? Python is not Java. some_var = '' is good enough

Comment: @RestRisiko: How do you write it in Java?

Comment: no idea - but using str(..) here does not make sense

Comment: @RestRisiko You missed the int(0) as well.

Comment: For this kind of analysis (and more complicated ones) in Python I would simply recommend to use http://www.scipy.org/, no need to reinvent the wheel ;-). Thanks

Comment: @khachik I'm no Java fan, but Java does have string literals. :)

Comment: @Chris Taylor: Where have you seen code using `and` like that?  Can you provide a quote or a link or a reference?  That's a very, very wrong thing.  Where did you see it?

Comment: @RestRisiko: sure it doesn't make sense. In Java either.

Answer (score 8):

You're misinterpreting how `and` works. To test if two values are in a list, use:

```
if comp1 in d1[person] and comp2 in d1[person]:
  ...
```

Your version does something else. It binds like this: `if (comp1) and (comp2 in d1[person])`. In other words, it interprets `comp1` as a truth value, and then does a boolean `and` with your list inclusion check. This is valid code, but it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This should run quite a bit faster because it removes an extra layer of iteration. Hope it helps.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

def get_competencies():
    return {
        "User X": [124, 198, 2244],
        "User Y": [129, 254, 198, 2244]
    }

def get_adjacency_pairs(c):
    pairs = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for items in c.itervalues():
        items = set(items)  # remove duplicates
        for a,b in combinations(items, 2):
            pairs[a][b] += 1
            pairs[b][a] += 1
    return pairs

def make_row(lst, fmt):
    return ''.join(fmt(i) for i in lst)

def make_table(p, fmt="{0:>8}".format, nothing=''):
    labels = list(p.iterkeys())
    labels.sort()

    return [
        make_row([""] + labels, fmt)
    ] + [
        make_row([a] + [p[a][b] if b in p[a] else nothing for b in labels], fmt)
        for a in labels
    ]

def main():
    c = get_competencies()
    p = get_adjacency_pairs(c)
    print('\n'.join(make_table(p)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

results in

```
             124     129     198     254    2244
     124                       1               1
     129                       1       1       1
     198       1       1               1       2
     254               1       1               1
    2244       1       1       2       1
```

... obviously a 400-column table is a bit much to print to screen; I suggest using csv.writer() to save it to a file which you can then work on in Excel or OpenOffice.

Comment: Nice use of `lambda` for the nested dictionary instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation here means that your two loops aren't nested. You first iterate through `competencies_list` and set `common_competencies` to the empty string 400 times, then iterate through `competencies_list` again and do what phooji explained. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do.

Comment: apologies, the indentation has appeared wrong when I have entered this on stack overflow - the second loop is indented to become nested within the first loop.